# Control Android Emulator and an App from Open Office Calc

Tags: android, android-emulator, openoffice-calc

I am trying to implement an Open Office Calc Macro which, has to read some strings from a column cell and start an android app to search for the string, then extract the data. To do so, I am using the following logic:
•   I am using an android emulator (BlueStacks) on my windows laptop
•   Start from the macro, the emulator, and within it, the target app.
•   Select search in the App
•   Paste the string
•   Start search
•   Collect the data
•   Return to the Calc

Can anyone here give some starting points regarding the communication between Calc ↔ BlueStacks ↔ Android App

Answer (score 1):

The Python [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) library can be imported in LibreOffice macros to call external `.dll` or `.so` libraries.

However, according to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/BlueStacks/comments/9us5b8/api_available_trying_to_list_running_apps_from/), BlueStacks does not offer an API unless you are a developer partner.

Instead, you could use AutoHotkey to simulate clicks and keystrokes on the appropriate windows.